# How to programmatically trigger presentation mode in JavaScript add-in for PowerPoint?

Tags: javascript, ms-office, powerpoint, office-js

We have a method to check current state of the PowerPoint document: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn482495.aspx

> Document.getActiveViewAsync

[image]

I can also listen to changes of the state: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn482501.aspx

> ActiveViewChanged event

And I'm already using is as follows:

```
var _hideArrowInPresentationMode = function(e) {
    var presentationMode = (e.activeView === "read"); // can inline variable but I find 'presentationMode' more descriptive
    if (presentationMode) {
        $("#left").hide();
    } else {
        $("#left").show();
    }
};

Office.context.document.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.ActiveViewChanged, _hideArrowInPresentationMode);
```

---

**Is there an API method allowing me to trigger presentation mode?**

For some reason I cannot find it in the docs.

---

Why do I want to trigger presentation mode? When user presses F5 it by default goes to presentation mode. However, if the focus is in the add-in, it refreshes the add-in. I'm listening for F5 key and preventing refresh but I'd like to go into presentation mode to ensure consistent behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no API in PowerPoint to enter presentation mode. Feel free to request this API on the [Office Developer Platform's Uservoice](http://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/83526-office-js)!

Comment: Looking at @Gab Royer's bio - he works at Microsoft - that's enough of credentials for me. Accepting answer.

Comment: Hello, Gab! Could have a look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36063158/overlay-item-for-all-slides-in-powerpoint